# how to deal with python projects on a freebsd (freenas) system

Tags: python, freebsd

I'm struggling with executing a python script on my freenas (freebsd) environment.

I created a Jail, where I installed python via

```
pkg install python
```

and tried to execute the program with the command

```
python filename.py
```

But now its mentioning that it requires a specific module

```
ImportError: No module named simplejson
```

which I also installed via

```
pkg install ...
```

the next attempt to execute the script mentioned a different module.

Is it really the case for python, that you have to install each module per request from an executed program? Or is there a way to determine which module the 3rd party program needs and install it in upfront?

And how do you search for the corresponding module in the repo? Because for the missing sqlite3 module I had to write

```
pkg install databases/python-sqlite3
```

How do I get now the correct name for the simplejson module which is mentioned before?

Can you help me out there?

Comment: Does your program come with a `setup.py` or `requirements.txt`?

Comment: nope, only these files are present: NMA.py          daemon.py       subliminal.ini  subliminal.py

Comment: @Daxcode if no one bothered to package it correctly (or at all it appears) - then yes, you just have to keep trying it, and installing modules until dependences are met and it works

Comment: @JonClements thanks for the hint. And how do I get the right module name for the pkg install statement? because pkg install simplejson won't find anything in the repo. Is there some kind of reference table or smth like?

Comment: @Daxcode no idea, but typing *freebsd python pkg python modulename* into the big G seems to get good results for simplejson...

Comment: @JonClements cool thanks. So conclusio there is that a python dev needs to document which library his/hers code is using so the user like me can install them in upfront. Cool language :)

Comment: @Daxcode if done properly - they'd be a one line command which'd go off and get everything needed (and potentially other dependencies) to run for you - then it'd all *just work* - alas for you, not in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first questions where already answered in the comments section. Here is the answer to the last question:

FreeBSD ports of python modules usually follow the convention of "py-" + modulename. The corresponding packages are usually named "py"+ python version + "-" + modulename

So it is py-sqlite3 and py-simplejson ports which install "py27-simplejson" and py27-sqlite3 for python 2.7.

Note: currently modules are only packaged for the default python version, for non-default python versions the modules have to be installed from the ports collection.